# Why this expression is not evaluated correctly?

Tags: evaluation

Look at the following code:

```
f[kx_, ky_] := -1*(Exp[I*kx] + 2*Exp[-I*kx/2]*Cos[Sqrt[3]*ky/2]);
H = {{1, f[kx, ky]}, {Conjugate[f[kx, ky]], -1}};
D[Norm[Normalize[Eigensystem[H][[2]][[1]]]], kx] /. {kx -> 1,ky -> 1} // N // ComplexExpand
```

Because of `Norm` and `Normalize`, the last expression should be evaluated to 0. However, the result is `0.000817968 -0.00266953i`, which seems to be too large to view as numerical errors.

What's happening here?

**Edit:**

I am actually wanting:

```
eigenvector = Normalize[Eigensystem[H][[2]][[1]]]
Conjugate[eigenvector].D[eigenvector, kx]
```

and then substitute value into it.
`Conjugate[eigenvector].D[eigenvector, kx]` should be a pure imaginary value but Mathematica gives non-zero real part.

BTW, `kx` and `ky` are real.

**Second Edit:**

```
 eigenvector = Normalize[Eigensystem[H][[2]][[1]]]//FullSimplify
 A = Conjugate[eigenvector].D[ComplexExpand[eigenvector],kx] /. {kx -> 1, ky -> 2} // N
```

gives `0.142624 + 0.124056 I`.

But `A` should be pure imaginary. ($A=v^\dagger\cdot \partial_k v$, so $A+A^* = 0$ because $v$ is normalized and $\partial_k (v^\dagger\cdot v)=0$)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I think the problem is that after Norm/Normalize you end up with many Abs, Im, Re, Conjugate, etc.  These are not proper complex differentiable functions, so when trying to differentiate them things break down.  It is not clear what `Abs'[1+I]` should mean at all.

Comment: @Szabolcs, then is there a solution to avoid this? I have found functions such as `Abs`, `Conjugate` extremely annoying in mathematica.

Comment: Well, what are you trying to accomplish?  You already know that the this is a constant expression, so its derivative is zero.

Comment: `Norm[Normalize[Eigensystem[H][[2]][[1]]]] // FullSimplify -> (*1*)`

Comment: @Szabolcs, edited the question accordingly

Comment: Use `ComplexExpand` to get rid of unwanted Re, Im, Conjugate, Abs *before* doing differentiation.  But can you still explain why you want to do this calculation using symbolic values?  When things are put in this form the result is so complicated that it is useless.  Think about why you want a symbolic result for this and whether it is really useful for anything.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I just need to differentiate symbolically and then substitute a value in it. I don't want to differentiate it by finite difference.

Comment: I do think it a fair question why we get a patently wrong result.  If `Abs'[]` is not clear shouldn't it remain unevaluated or generate an error?

Comment: You could try `Conjugate[eigenvector].D[ComplexExpand[eigenvector], kx]`.

Comment: @george2079 It does remain unevaluated.  One must explicitly force it to evaluate.  It would make an interesting question why and how `ComplexExpand` handles stuff such as `Abs'[2+I]` and whether that is acceptable.

Comment: @Szabolcs, it does not work. see my edit.

Comment: Instead of a plain `ComplexExpand`, try `ComplexExpand[eigenvector, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]`.  I do not understand why it didn't get rid of Conjugate ...

Comment: Re what's happening here: if you just evaluate your derivative without the `N` and `ComplexExpand` you'll see a lot of things like `Abs'[...]`, `Im'[...]` or `Conjugate'[...]`. These derivatives are taken out of necessity (because you made MMA calculate *a* derivative) and reduce the validity range of the answer. Namely, they make no sense for complex numbers as these functions are not complex-differentiable (their derivatives are fine in the real domain). In cases like these you first need to simplify to get rid of all such terms and only then differentiate.

Comment: Oh, I see @Szabolcs said the same hours ago :-) My apologies for typing before thinking.